# Как присвоить разное количество товаров в двух одинаковых swiper-slider на странице

Tags: javascript, слайдер

не могу понять что у меня в коде не так, я использую swiper-slider на странице, у меня 3 слайдера, проблема в том, у каждого слайдера свое количество элементов на экране. пытался присваивать каждому слайдеру на странице значение, но все равно у всех одинаковое значение остается, ошибку никакую не выдает.так же не работают брейкпоинты. Возможно задал вопрос некорректно, но я в первый раз пишу на форуме(.

```js
$(".js-slider").each(function () {
        const $slider = $(this);

        var slideCount = 4;
      if($slider.data("slide-count")){
       slideCount = $slider.data("slide-count");
      }
        var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
          slidesPerView: 1,
          spaceBetween: 10,
          // init: false,
          pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',
            clickable: true
          },
          navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
          },
          breakpoints: {
              640: {
              slidesPerView: 2,
              spaceBetween: 10
            },
              768: {
              slidesPerView: 3,
              spaceBetween: 20
            },
              1024: {
              slidesPerView: "slideCount",
              spaceBetween: 30
            }
          }
        });
      });
```

```html
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/css/swiper.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/js/swiper.js"></script>
      <section class="main-banner">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="swiper-container js-slider swiper-cut" data-slide-count="4">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                  <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="../images/slideOne.png"/></div>
                  <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="../images/slideOne.png"/></div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-button-prev"><img src="../images/icons/Arrow_l.svg"/></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-next"><img src="../images/icons/Arrow_r.svg"/></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
          <section class="main-block main-block__wrapper">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="main-block__content">
                <div class="main-block__top">
                  <h3>Товары со скидкой</h3>
                  <div class="main-button"><a class="main-button__text">Все товары со скидкой</a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-container js-slider swiper-cut" data-slide-count="4">
                  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                      <div class="product-card"><img class="product-card__img" src="../images/apple.svg"/>
                        <div class="product-card__text">ОКОРОК  охлажд. фасов. Русско-высоцкое, 1 кг</div><span class="product-card__price product-card__price--black">
                          <h4>109.90 ₽/кг</h4></span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                      <div class="product-card"><img class="product-card__img" src="../images/pasta.svg"/>
                        <div class="product-card__text">ОКОРОК  охлажд. фасов. Русско-высоцкое, 1 кг</div><span class="product-card__price product-card__price--black">
                          <h4>109.90 ₽/шт</h4></span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                      <div class="product-card"><img class="product-card__img" src="../images/actimel.svg"/>
                        <div class="product-card__text">ОКОРОК  охлажд. фасов. Русско-высоцкое, 1 кг</div><span class="product-card__price product-card__price--black">
                          <h4>109.90 ₽/шт</h4></span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                      <div class="product-card"><img class="product-card__img" src="../images/cocaCola.svg"/>
                        <div class="product-card__text">ОКОРОК  охлажд. фасов. Русско-высоцкое, 1 кг</div><span class="product-card__price product-card__price--black">
                          <h4>109.90 ₽/шт</h4></span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                      <div class="product-card"><img class="product-card__img" src="../images/apple.svg"/>
                        <div class="product-card__text">ОКОРОК  охлажд. фасов. Русско-высоцкое, 1 кг</div><span class="product-card__price product-card__price--black">
                          <h4>109.90 ₽/кг</h4></span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                      <div class="product-card"><img class="product-card__img" src="../images/pasta.svg"/>
                        <div class="product-card__text">ОКОРОК  охлажд. фасов. Русско-высоцкое, 1 кг</div><span class="product-card__price product-card__price--black">
                          <h4>109.90 ₽/шт</h4></span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                      <div class="product-card"><img class="product-card__img" src="../images/actimel.svg"/>
                        <div class="product-card__text">ОКОРОК  охлажд. фасов. Русско-высоцкое, 1 кг</div><span class="product-card__price product-card__price--black">
                          <h4>109.90 ₽/шт</h4></span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                      <div class="product-card"><img class="product-card__img" src="../images/cocaCola.svg"/>
                        <div class="product-card__text">ОКОРОК  охлажд. фасов. Русско-высоцкое, 1 кг</div><span class="product-card__price product-card__price--black">
                          <h4>109.90 ₽/шт</h4></span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-button-next"><img src="../images/icons/Arrow_r.svg"/></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-prev"><img src="../images/icons/Arrow_l.svg"/></div><div class="swiper-pagination slider__paginationView"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
<section class="main-block main-block__wrapper">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="main-block__content">
            <div class="main-block__top">
              <h3>Товары со скидкой</h3>
              <div class="main-button"><a class="main-button__text">Все товары со скидкой</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-container js-slider swiper-cut" data-slide-count="3">
              <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                  <div class="sell-card"><img class="sell-card__img" src="../images/salads.svg"/>
                    <div class="sell-card__text">
                      <p>Всем членам профсоюзов скидки в &quot;РИОМАГ&quot;</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                  <div class="sell-card"><img class="sell-card__img" src="../images/birthDay.svg"/>
                    <div class="sell-card__text">
                      <p>Скидка -20% в ДЕНЬ РОЖДЕНИЯ</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                  <div class="sell-card"><img class="sell-card__img" src="../images/retired.svg"/>
                    <div class="sell-card__text">
                      <p>СКИДКА -30% на КУЛИНАРИЮ</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-button-next"><img src="../images/icons/Arrow_r.svg"/></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-prev"><img src="../images/icons/Arrow_l.svg"/></div><div class="swiper-pagination slider__paginationView"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы каждый раз инициализируете `Swiper` для всех `.swiper-container` на странице.

```
var swiper = new Swiper(this, {
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось, только немого иначе сделал как мне кажется.

Answer (score 1):

в основном была ошибка в том, что он проходил по всем слайдерам, и обращался к самому последнему, поэтому вместо .swiper-container нужно было указать $slider,
плюс ко всему при указании переменной slide-count была ошибка.

```js
$(".js-slider").each(function () {
    const $slider = $(this);

    var slideCount = 4;
  if($slider.data('slide-count')){
   slideCount = $slider.data('slide-count');
  }
    var swiper = new Swiper( $slider, {
      slidesPerView: slideCount,
      spaceBetween: 10,
      // init: false,
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
      },
      breakpoints: {
          640: {
          slidesPerView: 1,
          spaceBetween: 10
        },
          768: {
          slidesPerView: 2,
          spaceBetween: 20
        },
          1024: {
          slidesPerView: slideCount,
          spaceBetween: 30
        }
      }
    });
  });
```